# Macro won't exit insert mode with Esc

Tags: macro

I record this macro:

```
ia^[sb^[
```

It should open insert mode, write a, exit, replace with b, then exit insert mode again.

you can bind it to @w with:

```
:let @w='ia^[sb^['
```

For whatever reason instead of a line with `b` I get the following `a^[sb^[`

Is there something I can do to get the esc key working in my macros? I've tried using `<Esc>` instead of `^[` as well to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your `^[` is not a literal `<Esc>`. More likely a `^` followed by a `[` (two characters);

You are supposed to insert a *literal* escape character (a single character displayed as `^[`). This is done with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: is there any way i can force it to use the one character ^[ as an escape? I have confirmed that this is not the problem, the Ctrl+V followed by Esc outputs the ^[ in a lighter looking font, for sure that's the escape key, yet instead of escaping i'm getting `è`

Comment: I gave you the right answer to your question. Why, how and when you get that è is another matter. Please ask another question.

Comment: Note that you type Ctrl+v Esc in insert mode, not normal mode.